# What does the "-Np1" option for the patch command do?

Tags: unix, patch

Someone sent me a patch and told me to apply it using the command:

```
patch -Np1 -i file.patch
```

Out of curiosity, I tried to find out what the -Np1 option does but the patch man page is curiously opaque on this. Can anyone explain what this does? Thanks.

Comment: It is a combination of -N and -p1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two flags. `-N` and `-p1`.

```
   -N  or  --forward
      Ignore patches that seem to be reversed  or  already  applied.   See
      also -R.
```

and

```
   -pnum  or  --strip=num
      Strip the smallest prefix containing num leading slashes  from  each
      file  name found in the patch file.  A sequence of one or more adja-
      cent slashes is counted as a single slash.  This controls  how  file
      names  found  in  the  patch file are treated, in case you keep your
      files in a different directory than the  person  who  sent  out  the
      patch.  For example, supposing the file name in the patch file was

         /u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c

      setting -p0 gives the entire file name unmodified, -p1 gives

         u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c

      without the leading slash, -p4 gives

         blurfl/blurfl.c

      and  not specifying -p at all just gives you blurfl.c.  Whatever you
      end up with is looked for either in the current  directory,  or  the
      directory specified by the -d option.
```